# How do I delete a file that's been fopen'd?

Tags: php, fopen

I'm using fopen and it's saving to my shared hosts /tmp directory. I fclose it, but the tmp file doesn't delete. How can I delete this?

PHP5, btw.

Comment: Purpose? Downloading a file to /tmp and then deleting it is odd.

Comment: I'm not downloading to /tmp. fopen is. I'm simply trying to read the contents of a file that is located on another server

Comment: `fopen()` should not save or create temp files anywhere. Post some code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)()

fclose just closes the stream, doesn't do anything to the file itself.

Comment: I can't unlink it becuase I don't know what it's been downloaded as

Comment: @Shamoon So how can you fopen it? Use the same path and filename for unlink as you did with fopen

Comment: No can do.. the path is not on my server.. it's http://www.somesite.com/file.txt.gz

Answer (score 1):

If the file is accessible via `$_FILES` (which is usually the case for HTTP file uploads), you can use `unlink($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])` to delete the temporary file. See: [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: It's not a POST upload.. I'm doing one of these:

$url = "http://www.somesite.com/file.txt.gz";
$handle = fopen( "compress.zlib://$url", "r" );